# Meaning of this string \\.\c:

Tags: windows, file, winapi, ntfs

I'm reading [this](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/24252-ntfs-directcopy-method-from-napalm/#entry198142). Here I've found some code lines, for example: `wsprintf(szDrive, "\\\\.\\%c:", *lpszSrc);` I want to ask, what does this string give?

I tried to look for information but all that I've found is:

> In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH
>   characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the
>   Unicode version of the function and prepend `"\\?\"` to the path. For
>   more information, see Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces.

and this do not answer into my question, so asking here. As I think it should be connected with windows specific or NTFS but not sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%c` is the single character format specifier for [`wsprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx).

The code is used to generate path names of this form:

```
\\.\C:
```

This is the path to a physical volume. You use such a path when performing file operations directly on a volume, bypassing the file system. So you'd use such a path when implementing raw disk copy, for example. The documentation for [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#PHYSICAL_DISKS_AND_VOLUMES) has more detail.

This all ties in with the fact that the code you found this in performs a raw disk copy.

Comment: Oh, I thought you knew that bit. `%c` is just a format specifier for `wsprintf`.

Comment: So if I want to open file `C:\file.txt` to access its raw data I have to open with path `\\.\C:C:\file.txt` and there is no need for backslash after `\\.\C:`. Or I need to write `\\.\C\file.txt`

Comment: \\.\C: is for accessing the **volume** When you do that you access the raw disk sectors. If you want to access a file, use a file name and raw disk access is not for you.

Comment: Are you looking for more than this, or does this answer your question?

Comment: The real question that I'm looking for is how to make a tool to safely delete file. But it looks you answered to question I provided here.

Comment: You mean to make it not recoverable by forensics? That's pretty hard! But I don't think you need direct volume access. All the same it's very hard to get right.

Comment: Yea I know its hard but it is more for fun. But I think to reach that it is needed to use direct access of volume because files may be not consistent in disk.

Comment: You can use write through access to force the data onto the disk

Comment: To securely delete the file, you simply overwrite the contents of the file a bunch of times with random data before you then delete the file.  You can use `WriteFile()`, or `CreateFileMapping()`/`MapViewOfFile()` for that.

Comment: @Remy Why do you need to do it more than once? And what do you do about features whereby Windows stores previous versions of the file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I was under the impression that overwritting the file only once would not be guaranteed to be secure enough, that  forensics could still read residual signals from the previous data. But apparently NIST did some research and found that not to be the case... oh wait, NIST has been closed down due to lack of funding!